# Using Jquery to change [NAME HERE] from text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form and want the name input in the 1st textbox to replace the text [NAME HERE] from the select box which is output to the 3rd box as it does already.

```js
$('select[name=phrase]').change(function() {
  $('textarea[name=line]').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- start form -->
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="myForm">
  <div class="well">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Client's Name or Animal </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Example: John Doe">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Select Phrase or Enter Custom Text Below</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="phrase" name="phrase">
        <option>Please Select</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 1</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 2</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 3</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 4</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 5</option>
      </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Custom Word(s), Sentence or Paragraph</label>
      <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="line" name="line" placeholder="Example: I MISS YOU"></textarea>
      <span class="help-block" style="color: red;"><em>500 Words MAX</em></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: It unclear, When I type something in the input, should it change all the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead look for changes on the `name` input box, and then when a change does occur get the names, and replace all options with the name given using `.replace` and `.text`:

```js
$('#name').change(function() {
  const name = $(this).val();
  $('select[name=phrase] > option').each(function() {
    $(this).text((_, txt) => txt.replace('[NAME HERE]', name));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- start form -->
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="myForm">
  <div class="well">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Client's Name or Animal </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Example: John Doe">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Select Phrase or Enter Custom Text Below</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="phrase" name="phrase">
        <option>Please Select</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 1</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 2</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 3</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 4</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 5</option>
      </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Custom Word(s), Sentence or Paragraph</label>
      <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="line" name="line" placeholder="Example: I MISS YOU"></textarea>
      <span class="help-block" style="color: red;"><em>500 Words MAX</em></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

Example1: This will change the first option that contains `[NAME HERE]`

```
$("#name").change(function() {
  var opt = $("#phrase option:contains(\\[NAME HERE\\])").first()
  if (opt) {
    $(opt).text($(opt).text().replace("[NAME HERE]", $(this).val()))
  }
  $(this).val("")
});
```

**Working example**

```js
$('select[name=phrase]').change(function() {
  $('textarea[name=line]').val($(this).val());
});

$("#name").change(function() {
  var opt = $("#phrase option:contains(\\[NAME HERE\\])").first()
  if (opt) {
    $(opt).text($(opt).text().replace("[NAME HERE]", $(this).val()))
  }
  $(this).val("")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- start form -->
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="myForm">
  <div class="well">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Client's Name or Animal </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Example: John Doe">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Select Phrase or Enter Custom Text Below</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="phrase" name="phrase">
        <option>Please Select</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 1</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 2</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 3</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 4</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 5</option>
      </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Custom Word(s), Sentence or Paragraph</label>
      <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="line" name="line" placeholder="Example: I MISS YOU"></textarea>
      <span class="help-block" style="color: red;"><em>500 Words MAX</em></span>
    </div>
```

Example2 This will add a new `option` with the value

```
$("#name").change(function() {
  $("#phrase").append("<option>Custom Phrase " + $(this).val() + " 1</option>");
  $(this).val("")
});
```

**Working example**

```js
$('select[name=phrase]').change(function() {
  $('textarea[name=line]').val($(this).val());
});

$("#name").change(function() {
  $("#phrase").append("<option>Custom Phrase " + $(this).val() + " 1</option>");
  $(this).val("")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- start form -->
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="myForm">
  <div class="well">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Client's Name or Animal </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Example: John Doe">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Select Phrase or Enter Custom Text Below</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="phrase" name="phrase">
        <option>Please Select</option>
      </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Custom Word(s), Sentence or Paragraph</label>
      <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="line" name="line" placeholder="Example: I MISS YOU"></textarea>
      <span class="help-block" style="color: red;"><em>500 Words MAX</em></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.replace

```js
lastVal = '[NAME HERE]';
$('#input').on('change', function() {
  var newText = this.value;

  $('#select > option').each(function() {
    var getText = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(getText.replace(lastVal, newText));
  })
  
  lastVal = newText;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input">
<select id="select">
  <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 1</option>
  <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 2</option>
  <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 3</option>
  <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 4</option>
  <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This would modify every `option` that may exist on the page.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Of course. It's an example, to illustrate the utilisation of String replace. My goal is not a copy past of my code into an project.

Comment: I hear you, but I would just remind you that it's safe to assume that, with a simple question like this, that the OP is very new and if we don't point out things like this, they won't know any better and they will just take the answer as provided and then be back 20 minutes later with another question like "How to stop my code from affecting all the option elements on the page?"

Comment: Strategies for Learning from Failure. If he gets my script and don't know the principle of jquery selector. It's important to post a new question to learn that, or learn by there self. Thank for your note, I update the script to change this selector

Comment: As a learning & development professional, specializing in web technologies for the last 25 years, I whole heartedly agree that learning from failure is a very effective technique that cements knowledge. But, on a platform like Stack Overflow, we are also concerned with duplicate questions or questions that don't show any research or effort on the part of the OP to solve themselves. So, in this environment, IMHO, it's better to be thorough with answers, that's all. ;)

Answer (score 0):

When the `name` element gets changed, you need to loop over each of the `option` elements and replace the `[NAME HERE]` portion of the text with the value of the `name` element.

**NOTES (FYI):**

- It's a good idea not to ever give any element a `name` or an `id`
  of `"name"` because `name` is a Global property of the `window` object
  and using that with your HTML elements can cause issues in certain
  edge cases.
- Since you have given your elements `id`s, just use those as your
  JQuery selctors - - it's less to type and it performs better.
- You are not using the `label` element correctly. It's meant to be a
  caption for a form field and you can "connect" it to a field by
  adding a `for` attribute to it that has a value of the `id` of the
  form field it's a label for or you can nest the form field that it is
  a label for within the `label` element itself. You did have the `for`
  attribute set up on the second one, but you didn't have the value of
  the `for` set properly. Labels are very important to user
  accessibility, so you'll want to take care in their use.
- The JQuery team deprecated the use of shortcut event methods
  (`click()`, `change()`, etc.) quite some time ago. They now recommend
  the use of the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for event binding (shown below).
- Don't use HTML elements because of the default visual styling that
  comes along with them. Use the correct HTML element that conveys the
  meaning of the content. For example, you've used `<em>` below most
  likely because it produces italicized text. But, the real reason to
  use that element is to convey that the content should be interpreted
  as being stated in an "alternate voice or mood" - as if it was
  something someone said. For all visual styling, use CSS.

```js
$('#userName').on("change", function() {
  // Loop over the option elements
  $("#phrase > option").each(function(index, element){
    // Set the text of the option to an adjusted string
    $(element).text($(element).text().replace("[NAME HERE]", $("#userName").val()));
  });
});

$('#phrase').on("change", function() {
  $('#line').val($(this).val());
});
```

```css
.emphasized { color:red; font-style:italic; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- start form -->
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="myForm">
  <div class="well">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="userName">Client's Name or Animal </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="Example: John Doe">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="phrase">Select Phrase or Enter Custom Text Below</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="phrase" name="phrase">
        <option>Please Select</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 1</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 2</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 3</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 4</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 5</option>
      </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="line">Custom Word(s), Sentence or Paragraph</label>
      <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="line" name="line" placeholder="Example: I MISS YOU"></textarea>
      <span class="help-block emphasized">500 Words MAX</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat more complicated, but this solution allows for realtime updating of the select-box. This works in the following manner:

1. Save the initial value of the options into a variable.
2. On 'keyup' (or anything you want) do the following:

   1. Clone the template options and replace the placeholder.
   2. Remove the old options.
   3. Insert the new options.
   4. Update the select-box to have the option with the same index selected.
3. Trigger the event once to remove the placeholder from the view.

```js
// move content from select into textarea
$('select[name="phrase"]').change(function() {
  $('textarea[name="line"]').val($(this).val());
});

// realtime update select based upon name
(function () {
  var $input = $('#name'),
      $select = $('#phrase'),
      $optionTemplates = $select.find('option');
  
  $input.keyup(function () {
    var $oldOptions = $select.find('option'),
        $newOptions = $optionTemplates.clone().each(function () {
          this.text = this.text.replace('[NAME HERE]', $input.val());
        }),
        newValue = $newOptions[$select.prop('selectedIndex')].text;
    
    $oldOptions.remove();
    $newOptions.appendTo($select);
    $select.val(newValue);
  }).trigger('keyup');
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- start form -->
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="myForm">
  <div class="well">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Client's Name or Animal </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Example: John Doe">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Select Phrase or Enter Custom Text Below</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="phrase" name="phrase">
        <option>Please Select</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 1</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 2</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 3</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 4</option>
        <option>Custom Phrase [NAME HERE] 5</option>
      </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Custom Word(s), Sentence or Paragraph</label>
      <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="line" name="line" placeholder="Example: I MISS YOU"></textarea>
      <span class="help-block" style="color: red;"><em>500 Words MAX</em></span>
    </div>
```